Настроить отправку рандомных 7 строк в тг бота в определенное время
Написала бота для изучения турецкого. Вся навигация осуществляется кнопками keyboard. Осталось только добавить функцию ежедневной отправки случайных 7 слов из тхт файлов словарей. Для этого сделала команду через тгфазера. Такая комбинация будет работать? Где-то на глаза попадалась инфа, что инлайн и кейбоард кнопки вместе нельзя использовать. И вообще, нет ли ошибок в коде? Может кто-нибудь подсказать? Заранее спасибо!
import telebot
from telebot import types
import schedule
import time
import random

.....

dict = ['база.txt', 'время.txt', 'глаголы.txt', 'качества.txt', 'общие фразы.txt', 'одежда.txt', 'цвета.txt', 'человек.txt', 'числа.txt']

dict_contents = {}

for i in dict:
        with open(i, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
                dict_contents[i] = f.read()
                for x in f:
                        print(x)

.....

@bot.message_handler(commands=["dict"])
def words(message):
        words_to_send = random.sample(list(dict_contents.values()), 7)
        for word in words_to_send:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, random.choice(dict_contents[message.text]))
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, word)

schedule.every().day.at('10:22').do(words)

while True: 
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

